# How to access Fragment tag into another activity in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

`Hotel_Location.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/googleMapLocation"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`HotelLocation.java`:

```
public class HotelLocation extends Fragment {

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savaedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_hotel_location,container,false);
      }

}
```

`HotelDetails.java`

```
 public class HotelDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotel_details);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Location"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Direction"));
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColorStateList(android.R.color.black));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final MapsPagerAdapter adapter = new MapsPagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });


        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMapLocation);

        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 10000, 0,   
        this);

}
}
```

`supportMapFragment` is returning null at runtime.

Am i doing anything wrong. Can anyone please help me. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you set access permissions in the AndroidManifest file?
Besides this you have to specify Google Maps API key which you receive from Google Console to access the Google service for displaying the maps.
You also need google play services enabled on google console and then include google play services as android library project into your project..

Here is a good tutorial for how to use google map in android project:
http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/

Answer (score 0):

findFragmentById() method is a member of the activity and it tries to call any fragment within its layout container, not outside like findViewById() method. Your content view is R.layout.activity_hotel_details, but you are trying to access a fragment from R.layout.Hotel_Location.

You may initialize an instance of the map fragment and handle the fragment operations within the fragment class.